# Fail to mock with Intern more than once

Tags: dojo, intern

I have followed the guide from Sitepen to mock AMD modules ([LINK](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/07/14/mocking-data-with-intern/)), but when I try to mock the same Module twice, the mocking fails, telling me my mock has no constructor. It crashes in the AMD-Mocker here:

```
try {
    originalModule = require(moduleId); [...]
}
```

Has anybody ever stumbled across this issue and has found a solution for it? It does not help to create two test files, either.

Here is my compressed code:

```
define(function (require) {
    var registerSuite = require('intern!object');
    var assert = require('intern/chai!assert');
    var amdMocker = require('support/AMDMocker');

    registerSuite( function(){

        var Hello;

        return{

            before: function(){
                return amdMocker.mock('amd/Hello', {
                    'amd/Resolver': 'support/ResolverMocked'
                }).then(function (mocked) {
                    Hello = mocked;
                });
            },

            name: 'helloMocked',

            'greet': function () {
                var hello = new Hello();
            }
        }
    });

    registerSuite( function(){

        var Hello2;

        return{

            before: function(){
                return amdMocker.mock('amd/Hello', {
                    'amd/Resolver': 'support/ResolverMocked'
                }).then(function (mocked) {
                    Hello2 = mocked;
                });
            },

            name: 'helloMocked2',


            'greet': function () {
                var hello = new Hello2(); // here it crashes
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This should be fine. Where is the line `originalModule = require(moduleId);` -- in one of the modules being tested? I tried a test case using the code above and very simple implementations of Hello, Resolver, and ResolverMocked, where Hello just instantiated a Resolver. It worked as expected (well, as I expected).

Comment: Hi Jason, that is weird. The line originalModule = require(moduleId) is in the AMD-Mocker sitepen provided. There an exception is thrown... The implementation for Hello & Require is taken from the official Intern tutorial, but it is as plain as you did it I guess. I'll give it another try!

Comment: Oops, I didn't even look in AMDMocker for that :) What does your test config look like?